# Pulling if fan page is tagged in previous statuses from users

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-graph-api

I haven't worked with graph for a while, but I assume since they really out did themselves this time around with facebook API-  I'm coding a feed fetch in which would eventually pull all statuses that are public, with our fanpage tagged in them.

Explained:

Say Tommy just tagged our fanpage in a status.  His profile settings are public, and likes our page (obviously).  Can we, as a fan page, pull his status via API?  Query based on our fanpage id or something?

I'm not sure, let me know if this can be done.  We're doing the same thing for twitter, with hash tags and what have you.l